# How to hide sensitive information like a professional on my computer?

Tags: security, sensitive-data

Is there any way of hiding sensitive information? I know there is some old way provided by the **Microsoft** in their windows series. But that is so old and **unsecure**. Any buddy can get that data either by copying the whole drive or the suspected folder or uncheck the hidden option from menu and then walk through each directory. And now even their own **File Explorer** search can show that hidden data which I don't like. I want a particular trick or method which can hide
information that no buddy but me can find. So if such a methods exist, and someone here know it, then please share it with me.

Comment: You could encrypt a certain folder in Windows and the encryption will be tied to your account. This will prevent other users from being able to read those files.

Comment: Veracrypt hidden volume upto some adversary. There is a subject is called _plausible deniability_ that you might be interested...